# In a week versus After a week

Tags: word-usage

"I'll be back **in a week**" means "I'll be back after a week has passed" or "I'll be back after the next seven day's period is over".

I've done a great deal of research to find out whether "I'll be back **after a week**" is also valid, failing to come up with any answers.

If it is valid English, does the "after a week" version mean just about the same thing as the "in a week" version? Could they be interchangeable?

Or does the "after a week" version have a slightly different meaning, like "I'll only be back after a week has passed" or "I won't be back until a week has passed"?

Or is it just that few English speakers have chosen to use it regardless of it being perfectly grammatical as well as logical?

Comment: What does "after" mean?

Comment: I would say they were interchangeable, meaning 'I am going away for a week'. If the exact date of return is important, the speaker would say 'I'm going away until next Saturday' or similar.

Comment: I think the tendency is not to use 'after a week' as a standalone temporal. 'After a week spent climbing in the Alpes Maritimes' or 'after a week I'd rather forget' or 'after a week in the most southwesterly town in Cornwall' all sound natural. // Your last suggestion is probably correct (though 'irregardless' is ill-formed as well as usually not used).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your comment about my suggestion. I'm also glad you pointed out the error. Would you take 'You can remove the bandage in 24 hours' to mean the same as 'You can remove the bandage after 24 hours'?

Comment: Certainly (though "You can assemble the model in 8 hours" defaults to "It takes 8 hours to assemble the model". Context / logic is often important in disambiguating inherently ambiguous strings.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your feedback was very helpful. I must admit it IS tricky for non-native speakers of English though.

Comment: Rule 1 of English: English and logic are far from identical. Rule 2: It takes forever to learn (and by then some joker has changed it anyway). Rule 3: See the first 2 rules as an inspiration to persevere rather than a death sentence. English can be fun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Inspired and disheartened, I do hope so. Thank you again.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/227433/in-a-week-versus-after-a-week) to multiple sites. In general, only post to one site. If you don't get an answer there, delete it from that site after a couple of days and try again at the other one. (If it could reasonably be asked at both.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Tried to delete it, but it's still there because I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is vagueness:

- "I'll be back in a week", is a bit vague - like much of the English language...
- "I'll be back after a week has passed" is a bit more formal, a bit less vague but still a bit wooly,
- "I'll be back after the next seven day's period is over" is a bit clunky and never used by native speakers.

"I'll be back **after** a week" can be used interchangeably with "I'll be back **in** a week[s time - is implied]" - means the same thing, but is equally vague...  Both are usually understood to mean: "I'll be back in **about** seven days."

So, if you do not want to make a firm date / appointment and only want to say: "I may / or may not be back in about a week." Either are fine.

If you have a job interview or a 'Hot date', you may prefer to use: "I'm back next Thursday...", assuming today is either Wednesday or Thursday.